# modal popup goes behind the slider

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to open a Modal popup for customer details. I also have a slider on the site, however when the modal opens it goes behind the slider, and when I slide the page done it's completely visible.

[image: Here how it looks]

Html (Html for pop up:) and Css for popup:

As read that popup should be just before  **/Body tag**  so tried but didn't work
If you need any other info please let me know.

```css
/* Full-width input fields */

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Set a style for all buttons */

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Extra styles for the cancel button */

.cancelbtn {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}


/* Float cancel and signup buttons and add an equal width */

.cancelbtn,
.signupbtn {
  float: left;
  width: 50%
}


/* Add padding to container elements */

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  padding-top: 60px;
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto;
  /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}


/* The Close Button (x) */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 35px;
  top: 15px;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Clear floats */

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/* Change styles for cancel button and signup button on extra small screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .cancelbtn,
  .signupbtn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">×</span>
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

      <label><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
      <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle. This seems to be a `z-index` problem.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the z-index value on the modal until the modal appears above the slider.

Answer (score 1):

Observed the css property in below Example :

```css
.slider{
  background-color:red;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:9;
}
.pop{
  background-color:skyblue;
  position:absolute;
   height:200px;
   width:400px;
   top: 15%;
   left: 5%;
   z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<div class='slider'>Slider</div>
<div class='pop'>popup</div>
```